# What is the state of new format packages (pkgng) in recent FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd

So, I was searching around with no results about what is the state with new format packages on FreeBSD. As I understand after this spring's security issue package building has been postponed. And they are not available to current date, right? Any idea when new package's repositories will be available?

Comment: Anything in your question that isn't adequately addressed by [the `pkgng` wiki page](https://wiki.freebsd.org/pkgng)?

Comment: For the time being use `portmaster` for source compilation. Follow the pkgng wiki and stay up to date.

Answer (score 1):

The state of pkgng in FreeBSD: "beta"
Pkgng packages aren't available since Nov 2012's security incident.
"Target dates for when service may be resumed have not been released."

Reference: [pkgng wiki](https://wiki.freebsd.org/pkgng)